# Simple iterate DOM element does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

this supposed to be easy task, but in fact i spent hour to solve this matter, i googled and found no solution yet, basically i would like to iterate dom element (div with IDs), here's my code:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("#pinlocation").each(function(index){
        alert(index+":"+$j(this).text());
    });

});
```

on the content:

```
   <div id="pinlocation">Test1</div>
   <div id="pinlocation">Test2</div>
```

i replicate the error here: http://www.doxadigital.com/scrape/dummy.php

as you see, this script fails to get second "pinlocation". Any idea what did i go wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The fact that you're giving two different things identical identifiers can't be a good thing.

Comment: It is invalid to have two elements with the same ID.

Comment: `id` needs to be unique, use a class; `class="pinlocation"` & `".pinlocation"` as the selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your html is invalid because you have used the same id for more than one element. that's why your code is not iterating for the second id.

see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Instead use class for the elements.

Answer (score 3):

an ID is supposed to be a unique identifier. Either change it to a class, or give them different IDs.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is simply that you **cannot** have two elements with the same `id`, the second one will be ignored.

You could try changing your `id="pinlocation"` to `class="pinlocation"` and then do:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j(".pinlocation").each(function(index){
        alert(index+":"+$j(this).text());
    });
});
```

which should now work properly.

Comment: OMG, after years of coding, i never know this rule before... Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You have same id for two controls which should not be so. You can mould down your selector to iterate but `this is bad practice and must not be used unless you have no other option`. `Its better to put some class in both and using class selector`.

**change**

```
$j("#pinlocation")
```

**To**

```
$j("[id=pinlocation]")
```

**Your code**

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("[id=pinlocation]").each(function(index){
        alert(index+":"+$j(this).text());
    });    
});
```

**Using class selector (Recommended)**

```
  <div id="pinlocation1" class="someclass">Test1</div>
  <div id="pinlocation2" class="someclass">Test2</div>


$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j(".someclass").each(function(index){
        alert(index+":"+$j(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Why suggesting such a bad practice? There should never be two elements with the same ID in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Its a very simple solution, change your id to a class.

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j(".pinlocation").each(function(index){
        alert(index+":"+$j(this).text());
    });

});
<div class="pinlocation">Test1</div>
```

NB. All ID's should be unique.